# Dockerhub repo image parse is not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

While build Dockerfile got error

error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value:

My Dockerfile code

```
  FROM cloud.docker.com/repository/registry1.docker.io/sundardockers/testrepo1
```

Yesterday this is working fine for me . Today i am getting error

```
error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!doctype html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n\n<head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    <title>404 : Docker</title>\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n    <style>\n    * {\n        line-height: 1.2;\n        margin: 0;\n    }\n\n    html {\n        color: #71859d;\n        display: table;\n        height: 100%;\n        text-align: center;\n        width: 100%;\n    }\n\n    body {\n        background: #fff;\n        display: table-cell;\n        font-family: \"HelveticaNeue-Light\", \"Helvetica Neue Light\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, \"Lucida Grande\", sans-serif;\n        font-weight: 300;\n        margin: 2em auto;\n        vertical-align: middle;\n    }\n\n    a {\n        color: #22b8eb;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n\n\n    @media only screen and (max-width: 280px) {\n        body,\n        p {\n            width: 95%;\n        }\n    }\n\n    #message {\n        font-size: 21px;\n        text-align: center;\n        animation: fadein 2s;\n        -moz-animation: fadein 2s;\n        /* Firefox */\n        -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;\n        /* Safari and Chrome */\n        -o-animation: fadein 2s;\n        /* Opera */\n    }\n\n    @keyframes fadein {\n        from {\n            opacity: 0;\n        }\n        to {\n            opacity: 1;\n        }\n    }\n\n    @-moz-keyframes fadein {\n        /* Firefox */\n        from {\n            opacity: 0;\n        }\n        to {\n            opacity: 1;\n        }\n    }\n\n    @-webkit-keyframes fadein {\n        /* Safari and Chrome */\n        from {\n            opacity: 0;\n        }\n        to {\n            opacity: 1;\n        }\n    }\n\n    @-o-keyframes fadein {\n        /* Opera */\n        from {\n            opacity: 0;\n        }\n        to {\n            opacity: 1;\n        }\n    }\n\n    </style>\n</head>\n<body>\n    <div id=\"message\">\n      <img  src=\" data:image/png;base64,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
```

Comment: This is a strange repository name. Why not `FROM sundardockers/testrepo1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Hub suggests to use `sundardocker/testrepo1` as a repository name:
[sundardockers/testrepo1](https://hub.docker.com/r/sundardockers/testrepo1)